# What is the dimension of the image of T?

Tags: linear-transformations

I have a question
Let $T : \mathbb{R}^{28} →  \mathbb{R}^{31}$ be a linear transformation whose kernel has dimension 9. What is the dimension of the image of $T$?

Comment: What does the rank-nullity theorem have to say?

Answer (score 0):

We use the dimension formula https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_theorem_for_vector_spaces so we get $$\dim(\ker(T))+\dim(Im(T))=\dim(R^{28})=28$$
So plugging in your assumption that $\dim(\ker(T))=9$ we simply solve the equation to obtain the dimension of the image.